# IOS platform alarm with slack from firebase

Tags: firebase

1. I have webhook URL of the slack channel.
2. I have already setup alarm system by slack from firebase , but I just receive the first ios 
   platform cash message, not receive the second ios platform crash message from the slack.
3. I have already upload configuration screen shot.

please help me , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have already setup alarm system by slack from firebase , but I just receive the first ios platform cash message, not receive the second ios platform crash message from the slack.

The crash is same case , but it had not resend message to slack channel.